# Cant connect to AWS IoT Core via MQTT using AWSIoTPythonSDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I have followed the AWS tutorial step by step. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iot-core-publish-mqtt-messages-python/

I have created the open-ended policy with the *, registered a thing and attached it to the policy, generated, downloaded, and activated the certificates. I have tried to connect and publish to a subscription using both the AWS IoT SDK for Python v2 and the original sdk but neither work. The code I'm using is straight from AWS's demo example connection code but they just wont connect.

While using the AWS IoT SDK for Python v2 I get this error message:

```
RuntimeError: 1038 (AWS_IO_FILE_VALIDATION_FAILURE): A file was read and the input did not match the expected value
```

While using the original SDK I get this error message:

```
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

The python code I'm using:

```
# Copyright Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0

import time as t
import json
import AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib as AWSIoTPyMQTT

# Define ENDPOINT, CLIENT_ID, PATH_TO_CERT, PATH_TO_KEY, PATH_TO_ROOT, MESSAGE, TOPIC, and RANGE
ENDPOINT = "XXXXX-ats.iot.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"
CLIENT_ID = "testDevice"
PATH_TO_CERT = "certs/XXXX-certificate.pem.crt"
PATH_TO_KEY = "certs/XXXX-private.pem.key"
PATH_TO_ROOT = "certs/root.pem"
MESSAGE = "Hello World"
TOPIC = "test/testing"
RANGE = 20

myAWSIoTMQTTClient = AWSIoTPyMQTT.AWSIoTMQTTClient(CLIENT_ID)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.configureEndpoint(ENDPOINT, 8883)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.configureCredentials(PATH_TO_ROOT, PATH_TO_KEY, PATH_TO_CERT)

myAWSIoTMQTTClient.connect()
print('Begin Publish')
for i in range (RANGE):
    data = "{} [{}]".format(MESSAGE, i+1)
    message = {"message" : data}
    myAWSIoTMQTTClient.publish(TOPIC, json.dumps(message), 1) 
    print("Published: '" + json.dumps(message) + "' to the topic: " + "'test/testing'")
    t.sleep(0.1)
print('Publish End')
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.disconnect()
```

(I censored the endpoint and the certificate ID)

(I'm using a macbook air and on a public school network)

Answer (score 1):

I went home and tested it and it works perfectly. If you have this same problem, try troubleshooting your network. I think my school blocks MQTT or something.

Comment: If you have a theory that your school blocks port 8883 (which seems unlikely), you can verify that theory by connecting to one of the public MQTT brokers (google it). If it also fails, then you have 90% confirmation (unless there is some other problem).

Answer (score 0):

MQTT works with the particular port number 8883 which you will configure in myAWSIoTMQTTClient.configureEndpoint(ENDPOINT, 8883).

In one of my AWS IOT course I learnt that some network administrators will block all ports which are not commonly used, to avoid unwanted traffic and MQTT is something which is specific to IOT industry. This could be the reason why it did not worked when you tried in school network and it worked when you tried in your home.